# Array that stores objects of different classes in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, class

I defined Saving and CreditCard classes which inherit from the Account class, and for the last class I want to define (the Client class), I need a list that stores all of the client's bank accounts as Saving or CreditCard objects (and is initialized to the empty list). I'm having trouble making this "accounts" list that stores objects of different classes. Trying something like var accounts:[AnyObject] doesn't work...

```swift
//Custom Exceptions:
enum MyError: Error {
    case transactionLimitExceeded
    case overdraftError
    case creditLimitExceeded
    case deleteError
}

//Account Class:
class Account {
    var account_number:String
    var transaction_limit:Int
    var balance:Int
    //Initializer
    init(_ accNum:String, _ transLim:Int ) {
        self.account_number = accNum
        self.transaction_limit = transLim
        self.balance = 0
    }
    //Functions
    func getAccountNumber() -> String {
        return account_number
    }
    func getBalance() -> Int {
        return balance
    }
}


//Saving Class
class Saving : Account {
    func deposit(_ num:Int) {
        self.balance = self.getBalance() + num
    }
    func withdraw(_ num:Int) throws {
        //raise TransactionLimitExceeded if num is more than transaction_limit
        //raise OverdraftError if balance is less than num
        //otherwise, deduct num from balance
        if num > self.transaction_limit {
            throw MyError.transactionLimitExceeded
        }
        else if self.getBalance() < num {
            throw MyError.overdraftError
        }
        else {
            self.balance = self.getBalance() - num
        }
    }
}


//CreditCard Class
class CreditCard : Account {
    var credit_limit:Int

    init (_ accNum:String, _ transLim:Int, _ credLim:Int) {
        self.credit_limit = credLim
        super.init(accNum, transLim)
    }

    func getCreditLimit() -> Int {
        return self.credit_limit
    }

    func getRemainingAvailableCredit() -> Int {
        //Return credit - balance
        let balance = self.getBalance()
        let credit = self.getCreditLimit()
        return credit - balance
    }

    func deposit(_ num:Int) {
        //set balance to balance minus num
        let balance = self.getBalance()
        self.balance = balance - num
    }

    func withdraw(_ num:Int) throws {
        //Raise transactionLimitExceeded if num is more than transaction limit
        //raise creditLimitExceeded if remaining credit available is less than num (you might want to call the method getRemainingAvailableCredit)
        //Otherwise, add num to balance
        if num > self.transaction_limit {
            throw MyError.transactionLimitExceeded
        }
        else if self.getRemainingAvailableCredit() < num {
            throw MyError.creditLimitExceeded
        }
        else {
            self.balance = self.getBalance() + num
        }
    }   
}

//Client Class
class Client {
    var name:String
    var accounts:[Saving,CreditCard]() //<- ???

    init(_ name:String) {
        self.name = name
        self.accounts = []
    }

    func createSavingAccount(_ accNum:String, _ transLim:Int) {
        //Creates a Saving Account and adds it to the accounts list
        let s = Saving(accNum, transLim)
        accounts += [s]
    }

    func createCreditCardAccount(_ accNum:String, _ transLim:Int, _ credLim:Int) {
        //Creates a Credit Card Account and adds it to the accounts list
        let c = CreditCard(accNum, transLim, credLim)
        accounts += [c]
    }

    func transferBetweenAccounts(_ account1:Account, _ account2:Account, _ num:Int) {
        //Withdraw num from account1 and deposit it to account2
        //Do this by calling the method withdraw from account1 and deposit from account2
        var account1Index = 0
        var account2Index = 0
        for i in 0...accounts.count-1 {
            let account =  accounts[i]
            if account.getAccountNumber() == account1.getAccountNumber() {
                account1Index = i
            }
            else if account.getAccountNumber() == account2.getAccountNumber() {
                account2Index = i
            }
        }
        self.accounts[account1Index].withdraw(num)
        self.accounts[account2Index].deposit(num)
    }

}
```

Comment: You can only create a homogenous array in Swift. Please refer [Heterogenous array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49252213/heterogeneous-generic-container-in-swift)

Comment: @Lee What is error show ?

Answer (score 1):

Make an array of the superclass.

```
var accounts = [Account]()
```

Comment: I tried, it says "value of type 'Account' has no member 'withdraw' or 'deposit'"

Comment: @JiwooLee That is, in my opinion, a design mistake. An Account class like yours should have default withdraw and deposit functions.

Answer (score 0):

`Account` should be a `protocol` and `Saving & CreditCard` should conform to it as below. Also currency should always be `Decimal` instead of `Int`.

```
protocol Account {
    var accountNumber: String { get set }
    var transactionLimit: Decimal { get set }
    var balance: Decimal { get set }
    func deposit(_ amount: Decimal)
    func withdraw(_ amount: Decimal) throws
}


//Saving Class
class Saving: Account {

    var accountNumber: String
    var transactionLimit: Decimal
    var balance: Decimal

    init(_ accountNumber: String, _ transactionLimit: Decimal) {
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber
        self.transactionLimit = transactionLimit
        self.balance = 0
    }

    func deposit(_ amount: Decimal) {
        self.balance = self.balance + amount
    }

    func withdraw(_ amount: Decimal) throws {
        //raise TransactionLimitExceeded if num is more than transaction_limit
        //raise OverdraftError if balance is less than num
        //otherwise, deduct num from balance
        if amount > self.transactionLimit {
            throw MyError.transactionLimitExceeded
        }
        else if self.balance < amount {
            throw MyError.overdraftError
        }
        else {
            self.balance = self.balance - amount
        }
    }
}


//CreditCard Class
class CreditCard : Account {

    var creditLimit: Decimal
    var accountNumber: String
    var transactionLimit: Decimal
    var balance: Decimal

    init(_ accountNumber: String, _ transactionLimit: Decimal, _ creditLimit: Decimal) {
        self.accountNumber = accountNumber
        self.transactionLimit = transactionLimit
        self.balance = 0
        self.creditLimit = creditLimit
    }

    func getRemainingAvailableCredit() -> Decimal {
        return self.creditLimit - self.balance
    }

    func deposit(_ amount: Decimal) {
        //set balance to balance minus amount
        self.balance = self.balance - amount
    }

    func withdraw(_ amount: Decimal) throws {
        //Raise transactionLimitExceeded if num is more than transaction limit
        //raise creditLimitExceeded if remaining credit available is less than num (you might want to call the method getRemainingAvailableCredit)
        //Otherwise, add num to balance
        if amount > self.transactionLimit {
            throw MyError.transactionLimitExceeded
        }
        else if self.getRemainingAvailableCredit() < amount {
            throw MyError.creditLimitExceeded
        }
        else {
            self.balance = self.balance + amount
        }
    }
}

//Client Class
class Client {
    var name: String
    var accounts = [Account]()

    init(_ name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }

    func createSavingAccount(_ accountNumber: String, _ transactionLimit: Decimal) {
        //Creates a Saving Account and adds it to the accounts list
        accounts += [Saving(accountNumber, transactionLimit)]
    }

    func createCreditCardAccount(_ accountNumber: String, _ transactionLimit: Decimal, _ creditLimit: Decimal) {
        //Creates a Credit Card Account and adds it to the accounts list
        accounts += [CreditCard(accountNumber, transactionLimit, creditLimit)]
    }

    func transfer(_ from: Account, _ to: Account, _ amount: Decimal) {
        do {
            try from.withdraw(amount)
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
        to.deposit(amount)
    }
}
```

Comment: While I like your solution, this isn't a code review site so it's a little too ambitious

Comment: thanks though. I'm a total beginner in Swift so it helps :)